# How can I easily concatenate typescript variable with string in html tag?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

This is my html code with ionic 2

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let job of allFreeJobs;let elementid=index">
     <p>
        <span id="m{{elementid}}" (click)="showMore(elementid)" color="primaryAdmin">...<ion-icon name="bicycle"></ion-icon></span>
      </p>
</ion-item>
```

From the code above this is my area of concentration:

```
... id="m{{elementid}}" ...
```

How can I easily concatenate m with the variable elementid? This is not working for me.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

As explained in [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-or-interpolation), you can use interpolation:

```
id="{{'m' + elementid}}"
```

or property binding:

```
[id]="'m' + elementid"
```

Answer (score 5):

you can do this  using square brackets,

```
   [attr.id]="m+'elementid'"
```

Comment: it should be `[attr.id]="m+'elementid'"`

Answer (score 4):

to make interpolation in the attribite of html element in angular you should use `[attr.attrName]="expression"` or in your case `[attr.id]="'m' + elementid"`

Comment: this might definitely be wrong since you kept the variable 'elementid' in a quote