# replace for an interpolation in angular inputs

Tags: angular

I am iterating over an array and display an angular component each time.

```
<div *ngFor="let category of categories; let i=index" id="category_{{i}}">
 <app-category
          [inputId]="'category_'[i]"
  </app-category>
</div>
```

the category component is recursive and i need to send this inputId and use it as html id like this

```
id="{{inputId}}_{{i}}"
```

app-cateogry.html

```
<!--Some html -->
    <div *ngFor="let subCategory of subCategories; let i=index" id="subCategory_{{i}}">
     <app-category
              [inputId]="'category_'[i]"
      </app-category>
    </div>
```

the problem is I cannot send the index as I tried above. 
I have also tried with interpolation (`[inputId]="'category_'{{i}}"`) but that won't work for inputs

What I am trying to achieve is to have on a sub category component an id like "category_categoryIndex_subCategory_subCategoryIndex"

Comment: `inputId="category_{{i}}"`

Comment: You will find the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44725705/1009922).

Answer (score 3):

You can use as below:

```
[inputId]="{{'category_'+ i}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution `[inputId]="'category_'+i"`; you cannot use interpolation for inputs, so I concatenated the string 'category' with index