# How to concatenate string in template?

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to create a unique id in the template:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb"+{{data.id}} />
<label for="cb"+{{data.id}}>
   <img class="card-image" [src]="imgUrl"/>
</label>
```

The `data` is a component object that has string id property:

```
@Input() data: Constructor;
```

But I get this error:

> ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '+{{data.id}}' is not a valid attribute name.**

My question is how can I concatenate string in the template with property object defined in the component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternative to the solution in the other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44725705/6513921), you could also do the following

1. The interpolation must be inside the quotes.
2. The plus symbol isn't required.

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="cb{{data.id}}" />
<label for="cb{{data.id}}">
  <img class="card-image" [src]="imgUrl"/>
</label>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gcqzrr?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use property binding

```
<input type="checkbox" [id]="'cb' + data.id" />
<label [for]="'cb'+ data.id">
    <img class="card-image" [src]="imgUrl"/>
</label>
```

Working example: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8eepqd?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Did you test your solution before posting it, this won't work you cant simply bind to id, angular will throw an error/

Comment: @B45i Are you sure about that? It worked just fine for me

Comment: Yup, You have to use [attr.id] just binding to id won'twork, can you paste  stackblitz URL of the code which worked?

Comment: Added the link to the answer :)

Comment: My bad, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like that.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="{{'cb' + data.id}}" />
    <label for="{{'cb' + data.id}}">
      <img class="card-image" [src]="imgUrl"/>
    </label>
```

I have added at the label some `''` maybe it will help

Answer (score 0):

You set dynamic id like below for your checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" [id]="'cb'+name">
```